# Microseconds timer with Carbon framework

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, timer, macos-carbon

Is there an equivalent to: Microseconds() we can find in the Carbon framework?

```
 **  Microseconds()
 *  
 *  Summary:
 *    Determines the number of microseconds that have elapsed since
 *    system startup time.
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    Return a value representing the number of microseconds since some
 *    point in time, usually since the system was booted.  One
 *    microsecond is 1 * 10^-6 seconds, and so there are one million (
 *    1,000,000 ) microseconds per second.  For reference, in one
 *    microsecond light can travel about 850 feet in a vacuum.
 *    
 *    Microseconds() doesn't necessarily advance while the computer is
 *    asleep, so it should not be used for long duration timings.
 *  
 *  Parameters:
 *    
 *    microTickCount:
 *      The number of microseconds elapsed since system startup.
 *  
 *  Availability:
 *    Mac OS X:         in version 10.0 and later in CoreServices.framework
 *    CarbonLib:        in CarbonLib 1.0 and later
 *    Non-Carbon CFM:   in InterfaceLib 7.1 and later*
```

Comment: Why do you need an equivalent? It's not in Carbon.framework, it's in CarbonCore.framework, which is inside CoreServices.framework, and is not deprecated.

Comment: Since you're using C++ you should consider using the standard library instead of Carbon. Look for information on the `<chrono>` library.

Answer (score 0):

`Microseconds` is a Core Service, and it is *always* accessible from Carbon. (Carbon sits on top of Core Services).

It originates from classic Mac OS as well.